# How to use a PowerShell variable as command parameter?

Tags: variables, powershell, parameters

I'm trying to use a variable as a command's parameter but can't quite figure it out.  Let's say `MyCommand` will accept two parameters: `option1` and `option2` and they accept boolean values.  How would I use *$newVar* to substitute option 1 or 2?  For example:

```
$newVar = "option1"
MyCommand -$newVar:$true
```

I keep getting something along the lines of *'A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-System.String option1'*.

---

**More Specifically:**
Here, the CSV file is an output of a different policy.  The loop goes through each property in the file and sets that value in my policy *asdf*; so  `-$_.name:$_.value` should substitute as `-AllowBluetooth:true`.

```
Import-Csv $file | foreach-object {
    $_.psobject.properties | where-object {
    # for testing I'm limiting this to 'AllowBluetooth' option
    if($_.name -eq "AllowBluetooth"){
    Set-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy -Identity "asdf" -$_.name:$_.value
    }}
}
```

Comment: You mean `newVar` but wrongly put in `myVar`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Typically to use a variable to populate cmdlet parameters, you'd use a hash table variable, and splat it, using @

```
 $newVar = @{option1 = $true}
 mycommand @newVar
```

Added example:

```
$AS_policy1 = @{
Identity = "asdf"
AllowBluetooth = $true
}

Set-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy @AS_policy1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that returns an error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Collections.Hashtable'.  Specifically I have a loop to get properties properties from a Csv and run them into Set-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy.  For a specific instance I'll say $_.name = "AllowBluetooth" and $_.value = $true (I wrote these variables out to confirm correct values.  However, I can't quite put it all together `Set-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy -Identity "asdf" @{$_.name = $_.value}` or `-$_.name:$_.value`.  It takes $_.value just fine though.

Comment: See edit. If you splat the parameters, you should include all of them in the hashtable.

Comment: If anyone is trying to use this answer and the example is not working for you, maybe you're doing the same mistake I did, for lack of attention: using the variable in the usual way writing `$AS_policy1` when I should be writing `@AS_policy1` with a "splatting" ampersand.

Answer (score 7):

See if this works for you:

```
 iex "MyCommand -$($newVar):$true"
```

Comment: Thanks manojlds, this got me a little closer. Literally, $newVar is $_.name and $true is $_.value (which equals "Allow"). The way I was doing it, it accepted $_.value for the value but not $_.name as a parameter. Using your method accepts $_.name as my parameter but not $_.value as the value... Saying cannot convert value "System.String" to type [type]. I'll keep trying other things though.

Comment: I got your method to work when -$($newVar) wants a string, but it fails on boolean values because it thinks it's a string.  I believe it's because the whole command is in quotes.  Any pointers?

Comment: @Fantabulum: `iex "MyCommand -$($_.name):$($_.value)"` should work then, for the reason I've explained in my answer. +1 @manojlds.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same Problem and just found out how to resolve it. Solution is to use invoke-Expression: invoke-Expression $mycmd
This uses the $mycmd-string, replaces variables and executes it as cmdlet with  given parameters

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, If you don't mind evaluating strings as commands, you may use `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$mycmd = "MyCommand -$($newVar):$true"
Invoke-Expression $mycmd
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try with:

```
$mycmd = "MyCommand -$($newVar):$true"
& $mycmd
```

---

result

Can't work because the ampersand operator just execute single commands without prameters, or script blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion empo, but this seems to behave the same way as my original.  I can post an excerpt of my actual script if that would help, but it involves several loops and Exchange commands so I think it would just cause confusion.